# Multiplying arrays resulting from multiplying arrays in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel

I've tried looking through some of the posts and I'm having trouble finding something that will help me in this situation.

I have a spreadsheet that has Total Sales, Retail Price, and Inventory for each week in a year for a list of 100 or so projects. These three pieces of info are displayed as columns repeated for the year, with a row for each item. 
[image: Excel Snip]

I was able to add up the total annual cells (every 3rd column) using `SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN(D3:L3),3)=0)*D3:L3)`

The next goal is to get a formula to calculate the weighted average retail. I basically need to find a formula that will end up with the `SUMPRODUCT` of an array of Sales data and Retail data.

I have tried to use some layering of `MMULT` and `SUMPRODUCT` but keep getting `#VALUE!` errors. Particularly with `SUMPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE((MOD(COLUMN(D3,L3),3)=0)),D3,L3)),MMULT(TRANSPOSE((MOD(COLUMN(D3,L3),3)=1)),D3,L3))` and with putting braces in there as well `=SUMPRODUCT({TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE((MOD(COLUMN(D3,L3),3)=0)),D3,L3))},{MMULT(TRANSPOSE((MOD(COLUMN(D3,L3),3)=1)),D3,L3)})`

Does anyone have any experience with this type of issue? I feel like it should be something that Excel can do without having to have separate sheets to calculate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your weighted average:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($D$2:$FD$2="Sales")*$D3:$FD3*$E3:$FE3)/SUMIF($D$2:$FD$2,"Sales",$D3:$FD3)
```

And also, to add up the Sales, you could consider:

```
=SUMIF($D$2:$FD$2,"Sales",$D3:$FD3)
```

I am assuming `FD` is the last column of data for the year, but change it if that is not the case.

Comment: Thanks! Just gave this a shot and it worked after I adjusted my column names. (I had a date concatenated with the 'Sales' which I omitted in this post)